# Alternatives to iptables for Firewall on CoreOS

Tags: coreos

If one doesn't want to directly edit iptables, what are some good alternative firewalls for CoreOS?

Some CoreOS-specific things:

- ease of setup (since CoreOS doesn't even have a traditional package manager or standard make/gcc built-in, also if possible [it should survive updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23311486/what-can-i-install-on-the-host-coreos-that-will-survive-an-update))
- possibility to initialize with cloud-config via `write_files` or some other means. (useful so no more steps is necessary when spinning up a new CoreOS machine and having it join the cluster.)
- securing docker container communication.
- securing etcd.